# Class-based user input validation

Tags: python, validation, user-interface

Having contributed to [this Community Wiki on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) regarding validating user input, I thought I'd finally sit down and write something more robust to do these kinds of tasks. I wanted something that would allow detailed configuration of the acceptable inputs, but without a huge list of arguments or spaghetti of processing code, and that would be easily extensible (for e.g. adding new validation options).

The code is written to be compatible with both 2.x and 3.x (tested in 2.7.9 and 3.4.2 on Mavericks), and has been `pylint`ed in both (*"Your code has been rated at 10.00/10"*). I have also included some built-in testing.

As well as any general comments/suggestions you may have, there are a few specific points I'd be particularly interested in feedback on:

- The use of classes (note I've had to disable `too-few-public-methods` - was OOP the right way to go, or should I have used e.g. a function factory?);
- The implementation of instance caching (is `Cached` sufficiently reusable in other contexts, or too tightly tied to `InputValidator`?); and
- How the testing is set up.

Code [also available as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/textbook/f0560a4555ba3c6dfeaa/e2a1abcaff24c65ae10dfd61a3d160efd4985ed4)]:

```
"""Functionality for validating user inputs."""

# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods

from __future__ import print_function

import sys

__all__ = ['InputValidator']


def create_choice_validator(choices):
    """Create a validator function based on defined choices.

    Notes:
      Attempts to create a set from choices to speed up membership tests
      with hashable choices.

    Arguments:
      choices (collection): The valid choices.

    Returns:
      callable: A validation function to apply to user input.

    """
    try:
        choices = set(choices)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    def validator(ui_):
        """Validate user input based on choices."""
        if ui_ not in choices:
            msg = 'Input must be one of {!r}'
            raise ValueError(msg.format(choices))
    return validator


def create_empty_validator(allow_empty):
    """Validate user input based on presence.

    Arguments:
      allow_empty (bool): Whether to allow empty input.

    Returns:
      callable: A validation function to apply to user input.

    """
    if not allow_empty:
        def validator(ui_):
            """Reject False-y input."""
            if not ui_:
                raise ValueError('Input must be present.')
    else:
        validator = lambda ui_: None
    return validator


def create_len_validator(len_):
    """Create a validation function based on input length.

    Arguments:
      len_ (int or tuple): Either the acceptable length, or a tuple
        (min_len, max_len).

    Returns:
      callable: A validation function to apply to user input.

    """
    try:
        min_, max_ = len_
    except TypeError:
        def validator(ui_):
            """Validate user input based on length."""
            if len(ui_) != len_:
                msg = 'Input must contain {} elements.'
                raise ValueError(msg.format(len_))
    else:
        def validator(ui_):
            """Validate user input based on length."""
            if len(ui_) < min_:
                msg = 'Input must contain at least {} elements.'
                raise ValueError(msg.format(min_))
            elif len(ui_) > max_:
                msg = 'Input must contain at most {} elements.'
                raise ValueError(msg.format(max_))
    return validator


def create_max_validator(max_):
    """Create a validation function based on input size.

    Arguments:
      max_: The maximum permitted value.

    Returns:
      callable: A validation function to apply to user input.

    """
    def validator(ui_):
        """Validate user input based on size."""
        if ui_ > max_:
            msg = 'Input must be at most {}.'
            raise ValueError(msg.format(max_))
    return validator


def create_min_validator(min_):
    """Create a validation function based on input size.

    Arguments:
      min_: The minimum permitted value.

    Returns:
      callable: A validation function to apply to user input.

    """
    def validator(ui_):
        """Validate user input based on size."""
        if ui_ < min_:
            msg = 'Input must be at least {}.'
            raise ValueError(msg.format(min_))
    return validator


class Cached(object):
    """Cache classes by positional arguments."""

    # pylint: disable=no-member

    def __new__(cls, *args, **_):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'cache'):
            setattr(cls, 'cache', {})
        if not args:
            return super(Cached, cls).__new__(cls)
        if args not in cls.cache:
            cls.cache[args] = super(Cached, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.cache[args]


class InputValidator(Cached):
    """Create validators for user input.

    Notes:
      Type is validated first - the argument to all other validation
      functions is the type-converted input.

      The following **config options are supported:

      - choices (collection): The valid choices for the input.
      - prompt (str): The default prompt to use if not supplied to
        get_input (defaults to InputValidator.DEFAULT_PROMPT).
      - allow_empty' (bool): Whether to allow '' (defaults to False).
      - min_: The minimum value permitted.
      - max_: The maximum value permitted.
      - source (callable): The function to use to take user input
        (defaults to [raw_]input).
      - type_ (callable): The type to attempt to convert the input to
        (defaults to str).

    Arguments:
      name (str, optional): The name to store the validator under.
        Defaults to None (i.e. not stored).
      **config (dict): The configuration options for the validator.

    Attributes:
      DEFAULT_PROMPT (str): The default prompt to use if not supplied
        in config or the call to get_input.
      VALIDATORS (list): The validation functions.

    """

    DEFAULT_PROMPT = '> '

    VALIDATORS = [
        (('choices',), create_choice_validator),
        (('allow_empty', False), create_empty_validator),
        (('len_',), create_len_validator),
        (('min_',), create_min_validator),
        (('max_',), create_max_validator),
    ]

    def __new__(cls, name=None, **config):
        if name is None:
            self = super(InputValidator, cls).__new__(cls)
        else:
            self = super(InputValidator, cls).__new__(cls, name)
            if hasattr(self, 'config') and self.config != config:
                raise TypeError('Configuration conflict')
        return self

    def __init__(self, name=None, **config):
        # Basic arguments
        self.config = config
        self.name = name
        # Select appropriate source for user input
        source = config.get('source')
        if source is None:
            if sys.version_info.major < 3:
                source = raw_input  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
            else:
                source = input
        self.source = source
        # Default configuration
        self.empty = config.get('empty', False)
        self.prompt = config.get('prompt', self.DEFAULT_PROMPT)
        self.type_ = config.get('type_', str)
        # Validation functions
        self.validators = []
        for get_args, creator in self.VALIDATORS:
            item = config.get(*get_args)  # pylint: disable=star-args
            if item is not None:
                self.validators.append(creator(item))

    def get_input(self, prompt=None):
        """Get validated input.

        Arguments:
          prompt (str, optional): The prompt to use. Defaults to the
            instance's prompt attribute.

        """
        if prompt is None:
            prompt = self.prompt
        while True:
            ui_ = self.source(prompt)
            # Basic type validation
            try:
                ui_ = self.type_(ui_)
            except ValueError as err:
                msg = 'Input must be {!r}.'
                print(msg.format(self.type_))
                continue
            # Any other validation required
            for validate in self.validators:
                try:
                    validate(ui_)
                except ValueError as err:
                    print(err)
                    break
            else:
                return ui_

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Allow direct call, invoking get_input."""
        return self.get_input(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Built-in testing

    from ast import literal_eval

    class SuppressStdOut(object):
        """Suppress the standard output for testing."""
        def flush(self, *_, **__):
            """Don't flush anything."""
            pass
        def write(self, *_, **__):
            """Don't write anything."""
            pass

    sys.stdout = SuppressStdOut()

    def input_test(_):
        """Return whatever is first in args."""
        return input_test.args.pop(0)

    # 1. Caching
    # Ensure caching isn't activated without name argument
    assert InputValidator() is not InputValidator()
    # Ensure caching is activated with positional name...
    assert InputValidator('name') is InputValidator('name')
    # ...and keyword name...
    assert InputValidator('name') is InputValidator(name='name')
    # ...and handles configuration conflicts
    try:
        _ = InputValidator('name', option='other')
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, 'TypeError not thrown for configuration conflict'

    # 2. Calling
    input_test.args = ['test', 'test']
    # Test both call forms return correct value
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test)
    assert VALIDATOR.get_input() == VALIDATOR() == 'test'

    # 3. Numerical validation
    input_test.args = ['-1', '11', 'foo', '5']
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, type_=int, min_=0, max_=10)
    assert VALIDATOR() == 5

    # 4. Empty string validation
    # Test empty not allowed...
    input_test.args = ['', 'test', '']
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test)
    assert VALIDATOR() == 'test'
    # ...and allowed
    input_test.args = ['']
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, allow_empty=True)
    assert VALIDATOR() == ''

    # 5. Choice validation
    input_test.args = ['foo', 'bar']
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, choices=['bar'])
    assert VALIDATOR() == 'bar'

    # 6. Length validation
    # Test exact length...
    CORRECT_LEN = 10
    input_test.args = [
        'a' * (CORRECT_LEN + 1),
        'a' * (CORRECT_LEN - 1),
        'a' * CORRECT_LEN
    ]
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, len_=CORRECT_LEN)
    assert VALIDATOR() == 'a' * CORRECT_LEN
    # ...and length range...
    MIN_LEN = 5
    MAX_LEN = 10
    input_test.args = [
        'a' * (MIN_LEN - 1),
        'a' * (MAX_LEN + 1),
        'a' * MAX_LEN
    ]
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, len_=(MIN_LEN, MAX_LEN))
    assert VALIDATOR() == 'a' * MAX_LEN
    # ...and errors
    LEN = 'foo'
    try:
        _ = InputValidator(len_=LEN)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, 'ValueError not thrown for {!r}.'.format(LEN)

    # 7. Something completely different
    OUTPUT = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    input_test.args = ['[]', '["foo"]', repr(OUTPUT)]
    VALIDATOR = InputValidator(source=input_test, len_=3, type_=literal_eval)
    assert VALIDATOR() == OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The use of classes (note I've had to disable `too-few-public-methods` - was OOP the right way to go, or should I have used e.g. a function factory?);

I like the idea of being able to have multiple different validation strategies encapsulated in different `InputValidator` instances. 
So OOP seems fine for me,
despite the `too-few-public-methods` warning.

> - The implementation of instance caching (is `Cached` sufficiently reusable in other contexts, or too tightly tied to `InputValidator`?); and

It seems a bit hackish. Is caching really worth the pain?
A classed called `Cached`, and `InputValidator` inheriting from it seems odd.
From an OOP perspective and Abstract Data Type consideration,
does it really makes sense to say that an `InputValidator` *is a* `Cached`?
Seems weird to me.

And it's not even easy to use.
To benefit from the cache requires a non-trivial custom constructor in  `InputValidator`.

I think it would be better to separate the caching,
and let the user *compose* a solution with caching from independent validator and caching components.

> - How the testing is set up.

It's great that you added the assertions,
it's easy to save one file on my PC and ready to play with it / break it.
You probably know this yourself,
but unit tests are best to be separated,
one independent case per method,
so when something breaks you have a method name to jump to.
And of course run the whole thing in a unit testing framework, for example `unittest`.

On a somewhat related note, it's better to split this line:

```
assert VALIDATOR.get_input() == VALIDATOR() == 'test'
```

to make it 2 distinct assertions:

```
assert VALIDATOR.get_input() == 'test'
assert VALIDATOR() == 'test'
```

So if one of them fails, you'll know instantly which one.

Lastly, why use ALL CAPS for `VALIDATOR`? 
Normally that's for global constants, so it looks surprising and unusual.

#### `create_empty_validator`

This is a bit of a misnomer.
The other validators include in their name some sort of requirement,
such as a length, minimum or maximum value.
This one sounds like it requires empty input,
but it's the opposite,
the purpose is to require non-empty input.
Perhaps `create_nonempty_validator` might be a better name.

I find it odd that this validator takes a parameter to decide whether it should actually do something or do nothing.
If I don't want to validate some condition-X,
the normal usage would be to not add the condition-X validator,
as opposed to adding an effectively disabled condition-X validator.
I suppose you did it this way to make it the default to reject empty input.
But this implementation is awkward and unnatural.
It would be better to remove from this method what doesn't really belong,
and refactor the rest of the program appropriately.

Comment: On `VALIDATOR`, `pylint` was previously complaining with `C:287, 4: Invalid constant name "validator_" (invalid-name)`. Perhaps it would be better to disable that warning for the test block. And I use `py.test` for bigger projects, but just wanted something inline for this standalone and relatively simple piece of functionality.